# 1-8, what's the next number?

Tags: lateral-thinking

$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, X, 9, 10, 11, 12  ?$

What is the number x in the above series?

> Hint: It's not 9.

Hint 2:

> there is a reason that the series is a series of continuous  from 1 to 8.

Hint 3:

> there is something with the numbers of digits.

Hint 4:

> position index. Here 8th term is 8 but 9th term can not be 9, instead the 10th term is 9.

Hint5:

> after "x" the series again continues till it reaches the 99th term and then 999th term and so on..

Final Hint: No more hints after this (it was asked to us when i was in 7th grade)

> 98th and 99th terms are 97 each. 100th term is 98.

Comment: As show the answers, you should at least point where to think. Because there's indefinite number of approaches...

Comment: "I know, it's 10 because its the next number x for which 840/x is an integer!"

Comment: It's not 9, because 7-ate-9! So the next one must be 10

Comment: @Inazuma you are right in a way, but there is nothing to do with the language, it's a simple number series.

Comment: @palsch there aren't any constants to solve this as you mentioned "840". You must check  the updated hints.

Comment: number of natural numbers less than n+2 not in ( 10^m for whole m)

Comment: @Jasen then what about the terms 98th, 99th and 100th?

Comment: it does that all that 97th term is 96 .

Comment: @Jasen then give the answer for "x"

Comment: the 9th term must be 8,  9+2=11, the numbers less than 11 not in 10^m are 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 - of which there are 8.

Comment: @Jasen finally right answer with right logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as this question hase ben taken off hold I'll post my answer

it's

> 8

because the sequence is

> $$ s(n) = n-floor(log_{10}(n+1)) $$

Answer (score 3):

I think it is

> nine, although you say it's not

because

> [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1,+2,+3,+4,+5,+6,+7,+8) says this and Wolfram|Alpha never lies. :P

Look:

> [image: Wolfram|Alpha response]

Comment: Your infallible reference also believes that $\small\sf s,a,n,t,a,c,l,a,u,s \to 1/10 (3a{+}c{+}l{+}n{+}2s{+}t{+}u) = 1/6 (e{+}i{+}2s{+}t{+}x) \to e,x,i,s,t,s,...$

Comment: @humn Of course. W|A is always right, so he exists. Didn't you know?

Comment: @humn Santa Claus _may_ exist! http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Does+Santa+Claus+exist%3F

Answer (score 2):

If it's not nine, than it's

> ten, the numbers could be just the 9-base  ;P

Comment: I was just thinking this and then your answer popped up. :) +1

Comment: @nicael there is a sequence which matches all and the next number.. can u justify this with 10?

Comment: What could else it be if you're just counting and there's no 9 in 9-base?

Comment: @nicael lateral thinking man

Comment: @nicael Do you call it "ten" if it is in base nine? Or is it just "one zero"?

Comment: It's ten in base nine, what's wrong...

Answer (score 2):

What about

> nothing ?

because

> This are numbers of planets in the solar system, Mercury=1, Venus=2, Earth=3, ...

and

> [since 2006 there are only 8 left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto#IAU_classification)

so

> It's not nine (anymore).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is

> $0$? And the sequence are numbers modulo $9$.